# PL SQL - Dynamic SQL in the where clause of a select statement

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I'm really new to Oracle PL/SQL, but experienced in Sql Server, and I'm trying to learn the ins and outs of it. For an introductory to it I've decided to optimize a query that is generated as a C# string and then executed as a text SqlCommand. So I'm trying to create a stored proc but to include all the variations of how the where clause can be generated, it's causing it to run ~40 seconds while the C# generated string executes in ~3 seconds. Here's an example of what I mean by the variations of the where clause...

```
declare  
searchType nvarchar2(3); -- options are 'x', 'y', 'z'  
searchDesc nvarchar2(4); -- options are '1', '2', '3'  
searchValue nvarchar2(5);

begin  

select count(*)  
from tbl_A a
where ((searchType = 'x' 
    and ((a.desc_X = searchDesc and a.value_1 = searchValue)
      or (a.desc_X = searchDesc and a.value_2 = searchValue)
      or (a.desc_X = searchDesc and a.value_3 = searchValue)
    )
  )
  or (searchType = 'y' 
    and ((a.desc_Y = searchDesc and a.value_1 = searchValue)
      or (a.desc_Y = searchDesc and a.value_2 = searchValue)
      or (a.desc_Y = searchDesc and a.value_3 = searchValue)
    )
  )
  or (searchType = 'z' 
    and ((a.desc_Z = searchDesc and a.value_1 = searchValue)
      or (a.desc_Z = searchDesc and a.value_2 = searchValue)
      or (a.desc_Z = searchDesc and a.value_3 = searchValue)
    )
  )
)

end;
```

So what I'm wondering is, is it possible to have a select statement that can execute dynamic sql in the where clause. Or does the entire statement need to be dynamic sql. Below is an example of what I'm questioning...

```
declare
whereClause varchar2(500);  
searchType nvarchar2(3); -- options are 'x', 'y', 'z'  
searchDesc nvarchar2(4); -- options are '1', '2', '3'  
searchValue nvarchar2(5);  

begin

select case
    when searchType = 'x' then 'a.desc_X = :desc and a.value_1 = :val'
    when searchType = 'y' then 'a.desc_Y = :desc and a.value_2 = :val'
    when searchType = 'z' then 'a.desc_Z = :desc and a.value_3 = :val'
    end
into whereClause
from dual;

select count(*)
from tbl_A a
where (
    execute immediately whereClause using searchDesc, searchValue
)

end;
```

When I tried to execute it as all dynamic sql, it still took ~15 seconds to execute. So if anyone has a better way of handling the many where clause variations, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: As for your question "does the entire statement need to be dynamic sql", the answer is yes. Based on your first procedure example and the time difference between the C#-generated version and the proc, I'm guessing the `WHERE` clause in the proc version is killing any chance of optimization - probably the C# version has a much more targeted `WHERE` clause. You could try duplicating the C# logic in the procedure and doing an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` on the resulting string, but I doubt that would give you much of a boost. This may be a case where you need to look for optimization elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too many ORs used like that will tend to make the performance suck.  If you're always going to have a fixed set of parameters you can do something like this:

```
declare

    stmt varchar2(1500);  
    searchType nvarchar2(3); -- options are 'x', 'y', 'z'  
    searchDesc nvarchar2(4); -- options are '1', '2', '3'  
    searchValue nvarchar2(5);  

    n pls_integer;

begin

    stmt := 'select count(*) from tbl_A a where (';

     case
        when searchType = 'x' then stmt := stmt || 'a.desc_X = :desc and a.value_1 = :val';
        when searchType = 'y' then stmt := stmt || 'a.desc_Y = :desc and a.value_2 = :val';
        when searchType = 'z' then stmt := stmt || 'a.desc_Z = :desc and a.value_3 = :val';
    end case;

    stmt := stmt ||')';


    execute immediately stmt using searchDesc, searchValue
    into n;

end;
```

Note that - unlike T-SQL - in PL/SQL we need to select our result set into a variable.  I have proposed an integer because your sample code is just SELECT COUNT(*).  Your real query will require a variable matching the query projection, perhaps a record type or a collection.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking this would probably be the way you would have to do it. I was trying to get away from having to concatinate all the parts of the query into one string since the C# code currently does this and it would be just moving the complexity from one environment to another. Thank you for the help though. I'll give this question a little more time to cook before I set this as the answer to see what else comes up.